# Диалоговое окно редактирования

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Нажали на кнопку. Вылезло окно с полем редактирования (т.е. текстовое поле с подгруженным текстом). Есть две кнопки - Сохранить и Отмена. Жмем сохранить и результат редактирования сохраняется. Как сделать вот такую вот штуку на javascript, jquery?

```
<?php
require_once "conf.php";
?>

<head>

<body> 
<?php

dbConnect();

$zapros=mysql_query("select * from spr_otdel") or die (mysql_error);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($zapros)){
echo "
<div class='panel' style='width:200px;'>
{$row['id']}  {$row['name']}<div class='selo' ><a href='#' class='btn-delete'>Удалить</a> | <a href='#' class='edit'>Редактировать</a></div></div>";
}
?>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".panel:even").addClass("alt");

    $(".panel .btn-delete").click(function () {
        alert("Этот отдел будет удален");

        $(this).parents(".panel").animate({
            backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7"
        }, "fast").animate({
            opacity: "hide"
        }, "slow")
        return false;
    });

    $(".panel.edit").click(function () {

        if (confirm("Хотите указать свой текст?")) {
            var s = prompt("Укажите свой текст:");
            alert("Вы указали такой текст: " + s);
        } else {
            alert("Вы отказались указывать свой текст");
        }
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.panel {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px;
    position: relative;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc
    }
.alt {
    background: #f5f4f4;
    }
.selo {
    font-size: 8pt;
    }
</style>

</body> 
</html>
```

Не работает этот кусок

```
$(".panel.edit").click(function () {
    if (confirm("Хотите указать свой текст?")) {
        var s = prompt("Укажите свой текст:");
        alert("Вы указали такой текст: " + s);
    } else {
        alert("Вы отказались указывать свой текст");
    }
});
```

Comment: а что именно не работает, яваскрипт работает, окошко выпрыгивает и текст вводится, что не так не ясно

Answer (score 1):

`$(".panel.edit")` => `$(".panel .edit")`
И так, на всякий случай: ваш кусок кода не отправляет никаких данных. Просто предупредил.

Comment: Я с вами согласен, он наверное не правильно указал селектор, поэтому и не работало